# laravel Blade foreach lists ->limit list based on id (not key)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I want to limit a list based upon a id.

So, if i have a country, I only want to have a limited lists with (let's say) Writers in my blade view. Next I want to select a writer a save/update the record.

Models are fine.

In the controller :

```
$writers= Writer::lists('name', 'id', 'country_id');
```

In the view, the countries a all ready in a foreach:

```
@foreach ($countries as $country)
<td>{!! Form::label('writer', $country->writer->name, array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::select('writer_id', $writers, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `whereNotIn` method? `Writer::whereNotIn('id', $idsList)->lists('name', 'id', 'country_id');` You need to pass an array with the ids on the `$idsList`

Comment: But how to get the changing country_id from the view form into the controller (tried something simmilair)?

Comment: If i understand you correct, you need to get the submitted input with `Input::get('country_id');` as you do with any other fields

Comment: Yes. Since I want to edit and save multiple rows, I use a foreach in a blade form. So country with id one has several writers. Writers belong to one country, but there is more then one country. I only want to see the writer from the country wich is the id.